# Is there a way to change an HTML image url to text entered in an input field WITHOUT using Javascript?

Tags: html, css

I am currently developing an online tabletop RPG character sheet (to be integrated with the Roll20 virtual tabletop), and would like to add support for the user to display a custom portrait of their character using a URL. Ideally, this would be via an input field on the sheet itself that would feed into the src attribute of an image, also on the sheet, which would then update with the given URL.

Unfortunately, Roll20's framework is heavily sandboxed and doesn't allow javascript at all, so I'm stuck with HTML and CSS only. With this limitation in mind, is there any way to achieve the user experience I'm looking for? (That experience being, the user sees an empty form input field and a blank image frame. The user pastes a URL into a form input field, and the image's src is then set to the URL given in the input, displaying the image.)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, if you need it based off the value of an input. But there are lots of people more experienced than I on this site, so you never know.

Comment: By the way, knowing which framework you're dealing with would probably be helpful to know.

Comment: write inline JS to the input to do this

Comment: @Chipster Good point. It's the roll20 virtual tabletop; I edited the post body to reflect this.

Comment: Also keep in mind that there would be no way to persist the change. They would need to re-enter the image url every time the character sheet was (re)loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Add some inline js to the onchange event of the for input, eg

```
<input type='text' onchange="document.getElmentById(myImageId).src=this.value;" />
```

Yes, this is javascript, however unless your framework is clever enough to strip it out it should run.